# Pass string value from FragmentContainerView to the Activity on button clicks

Tags: java, android, fragment

I've created an FragmentContainerView called GamePadFragment in MainActivity and I would like to get data from the fragment to the main activity. As the FragmentContainerView is relatively new method. I cannot find much info onto it.

I've placed multiple buttons on the FragmentContainerView. May I know how to get data pass (string) from the fragment on a button in FragmentContainerView is clicked.

```
String Pass:

from the `GamePadFragment` (FragmentContainerView) --> the Activity holding it

on button clicks
```

The current code in Main Activity is like:

```
FragmentContainerView gamePadFragment;

public MainActivity() {
    super(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gamePadFragment = findViewById (R.id.gamePadFragment);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .add(R.id.gamePadFragment, GamePadFragment.class, null)
                .commit();
    }

    // Set Default Appearance
    //int wd = gamePadFragment.getWidth();
    //gamePadFragment.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wd, wd));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use callback

```
interface MyCallback{
   void click(String data);
}
```

Activity implements this interface

```
class MyActivity implements MyCallback
```

send delegate to your fragment,
call callback function in your fragment